# Meaning of "have never been the worse for that"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Can someone explain what is meant by "have never been worse for that" in the following paragraph.

> Golan's book is good but its title is misleading. A whole chapter is
>   devoted to the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse and I'm willing to bet that
>   most professional mathematicians including, say, Grothendieck have no
>   idea what it is about, and **have never been the worse for that**!

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a stock phrase, perhaps more often encountered as *to be none the worse for it*.

*To be the worse for* something means "to be in a worse situation as a consequence" of it, and this phrase adds the emphatic negative *none* = "not at all". Your example could be paraphrased as

> Professional mathematicians have never suffered any ill consequence from knowing nothing about the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Comment: The same construction also occurs commonly in [none the worse for](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22none+the+worse+for%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and [so much the better](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22so+much+the+better%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.